# Laravel CSRF Protection and Mailgun

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mailgun

Mailgun is suppose to send a post request to laravel application, everytime it sends such request Laravel stops the request with the error

```
throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
```

I can't figure out a method to solve this issue?

I am using laravel 4.1

Comment: Looks like you may have a global filter set up on all POST requests that passes the request through 'csrf' before filter. Doing so checks that the token passed in the POST data matches the one Laravel has - in the case of a request from Mailgun, there won't be a token. You need to ensure the 'csrf' filter does not apply to this route.

Comment: I did that and removed the filter thanks

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa would be best to provide the solution that you implemented so that others can reference it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the routes by adding their URIs to the `$except` property of the `VerifyCsrfToken`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```